# Вывод блоков, не содержащих строку

Tags: php, python, bash, perl, awk

Мне надо выбрать из текстового файла блоки, начинающиеся со строки `interface`, и закнчивающиеся строкой `!`:

```
$ cat b2-s15.config.txt | awk ' /^interface/,/^\!/ {print} '
```

Вывод получается вот такой:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/x.1xxxx68
 description xxxxxx
 encapsulation dot1Q xxxx second-dot1q 968
 ip address xx 255.255.255.252
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/x.1xxxx69
 description xxxxxx
 encapsulation dot1Q xxxx second-dot1q 969
 ip address xx 255.255.255.252
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/x.1xxxx102
 description xxxx
 encapsulation dot1Q xxxx second-dot1q 102
 ip address xxxxxx 255.255.255.252
 ip access-group block_localnet in
 no cdp enable
 service-policy type control INTERFACE_SUBSCRIBERS
 ip subscriber interface
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/x.1xxxx103
 description xxxxx
 encapsulation dot1Q xxxx second-dot1q 103
 ip address xxxxx 255.255.255.252
 ip access-group block_localnet in
 rate-limit input 256000 50000 50000 conform-action transmit exceed-action drop
 rate-limit output 256000 50000 50000 conform-action transmit exceed-action drop
 no cdp enable
!
```

Теперь задачу усложнили, нужно вывести блоки, в которых отсутствует строка

```
service-policy type control INTERFACE_SUBSCRIBERS
```

Как это реализовать?

Мне не принципиально решить эту задачу именно на *awk* или *bash*, хотя и желательно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот просто регулярка:

```
/(?<=^|\r|\n)(interface(?:.(?!service\-policy type control INTERFACE_SUBSCRIBERS))+?\!(?<=(?:\r|\n)\!))/gs
```

Будет работать на php.

Пример https://regex101.com/r/lZ5pL7/1

Описание:

`(?<=^|\r|\n)` - с помощью позитивного просмотра назад определяем начало текста или перевод строки

`(interface(?:.(?!service\-policy type control INTERFACE_SUBSCRIBERS))+?\!(?<=(?:\r|\n)\!))` - группировка нужного фрагмента текста начинающегося с `interface` и заканчивающего `!`

`(?:.(?!service\-policy type control INTERFACE_SUBSCRIBERS))+?` - группа без обратной связи в которую попадают все символы между словами `interface` и `!` с одновременной проверкой на каждом символе через негативный просмотр вперед на отсутствие подстроки `service-policy type control INTERFACE_SUBSCRIBERS` после текущего символа

`(?<=(?:\r|\n)\!)` - позитивный просмотр назад после найденного `!`, чтобы он был найден в начале новой строки

**UPD**

Код php скрипта:

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents('file.dat');
$re = "/(?<=^|\\r|\\n)(interface(?:.(?!service\\-policy type control INTERFACE_SUBSCRIBERS))+?\\!(?<=(?:\\r|\\n)\\!))/s";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

echo "<pre>\n";

foreach($matches[1] as $s)
    echo $s . "\n\n";

echo "</pre>\n";
```

Тут файл `file.dat` это файл с обрабатываемым текстом.
В браузер результат выводится в таком виде:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/x.1xxxx68
 description xxxxxx
 encapsulation dot1Q xxxx second-dot1q 968
 ip address xx 255.255.255.252
!

interface GigabitEthernet0/x.1xxxx69
 description xxxxxx
 encapsulation dot1Q xxxx second-dot1q 969
 ip address xx 255.255.255.252
!

interface GigabitEthernet0/x.1xxxx103
 description xxxxx
 encapsulation dot1Q xxxx second-dot1q 103
 ip address xxxxx 255.255.255.252
 ip access-group block_localnet in
 rate-limit input 256000 50000 50000 conform-action transmit exceed-action drop
 rate-limit output 256000 50000 50000 conform-action transmit exceed-action drop
 no cdp enable
!
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: Не подскажете как правильно это перенести в offline? а то я что то не очень разобрался с генератором кода. Скопировал сгенерированный код в файл и попробовал запустить получилась вот так

Comment: user@Poligon:~/test$ php run_int.php 
<?
$re = "/(?<=^|\\r|\\n)(interface(?:.(?!service\\-policy type control INTERFACE_SUBSCRIBERS))+?\\!(?<=(?:\\r|\\n)\\!))/s"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
?>

Comment: @Izya12, обновил ответ. Еще вопрос: `!` в тексте не встречаются, кроме как они у вас отображены в примере? Или могут встречаться в других строках?

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо!!!

Answer (score 4):

можно воспользоваться такой конструкцией для программы *gnu/sed*:

```
$ sed '/начало блока/{:1;N;/конец блока/!b1;/исключение/d}' file
```

---

в применении к конкретным данным будет выглядеть так:

```
$ sed '/^interface/{:1;N;/^!/!b1;/service-policy type control INTERFACE_SUBSCRIBERS/d}' file
```

Comment: Не срабатывает :(

Comment: в каком смысле «не срабатывает»?